# Wie sagt man "i dont care" auf höfliche Art und Weise?

Tags: word-choice, politeness

> A: Welchen Wagen möchtest du morgen verwenden? Den roten oder den schwarzen?
>
> B: Egal, solange er funktioniert.

Ich weiß nicht, ob *egal* in diesem Kontext  passt.

Comment: _Egal_ passt. Wenn man einen ganzen Satz möchte: "Das ist mir egal."

Comment: Möchte man nicht uninteressiert scheinen, aber doch "egal" sagen, sagt man oft "Das ist mir *eigentlich* egal"

Comment: Das vorgebliche Duplikat ist auf Englisch, diese Frage auf Deutsch.

Comment: @jan Im Hinblick auf diese [Meta-Frage](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/14/if-the-same-question-is-asked-in-german-and-english-is-it-a-duplicate) schent mir eine Klarstellung nötig. Wir können bei SO sicher davon ausgehen, dass jeder Englisch versteht. Was bringt es, ein deutsches Frage-Duplikat offen zu lassen?

Comment: @guidot Reicht dir [das](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/807/15318) as Klarstellung? Übrigens würde ich *nicht* automatisch davon ausgehen, dass jeder Englisch versteht, nur weil man es geschafft hat, auf diese Seite zu kommen. Ein paar Grundbegriffe reichen hier völlig aus.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Zu dieser Frage fällt mir nichts, aber auch gar nichts ein.
Außer:

> - [das] spielt keine Rolle
> - [das] tut nichts zur Sache
> - [das] ist mir gleich[gültig]

Comment: "das tut nichts zur Sache" würde ich nicht analog zu "das ist mir egal" verwenden. "das tut nichts zur Sache" würde ich verwenden, um in einer Diskussion fadenscheinige Argumente, die nichts mit dem Thema zu tun haben, zu entkräften.

Comment: @Robert: Das kann man so machen, ist ja immer auch Geschmacksache, wer wann was verwendet, in meinem Duden jedenfalls heißt es unter *nichts zur Sache tun*: `Im gegebenen Zusammenhang nicht von Belang sein`

Comment: Auf die Frage "Welchen Wagen möchtest Du fahren?" ist die Antwort "Ist mir egal" und "tut nichts zur Sache" ein risieger Unterschied.

Comment: @Robert Genau. "tut nichts zur Sache" hiesse sowas wie "Wir reden doch grade drüber, ob wir uns scheiden lassen. Da fragst du mich, welches Auto mir nehmen? Mir doch egal."

Answer (score 5):

*Egal* passt in den Kontext und ist ausreichend höflich. Wenn du es noch höflicher formulieren möchtest, gibt es Varianten wie:

> Ich habe da keine besonderen Vorlieben.
>
> Mir sind beide recht.
>
> Das spielt keine Rolle.